# How to pre-fund wallets to execute smartcontract functions as Custodian for someone else?

Tags: transactions, erc-20, gas, signature, raw-transaction

Let's say we create multiple wallets (via HD-Wallet) for our users, so they don't have to care for their private keys.

The users will only have access to their public wallet address to receive Ether or ERC20 or ERC721 tokens.

But there will be some point when we have to transfer ERC20 / 721 / 1155 tokens from their wallet onto another wallet on the user's behalf.

When using custom smart contracts, we could add functions that allow a specific operator wallet to do so (with signatures or specific roles based on OpenZeppelin's [AccessControl](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/access-control)-contracts). But for the **conventional contracts**, that already exist, there is no function for our usecase available (and `approve` is not an option here because it also requires gas).

We can obtain the required private key for every single wallet thanks to the nature of HD wallets. But we have to **pre-fund these wallets** with Ether to pay gas fees, and I am looking for the best way to do so:

1. estimate the gas fees for the corresponding `transferFrom`-Method of the smart contracts (or whatever function is needed for execution)
2. send Ether according to this estimation into the wallet
3. try to sign and send the method call to the Ethereum node
4. if it fails because gas fees were rising in the meanwhile, return to step §1 and add 10 percent on top for pre-funding or something like that

I learned that using the **defender**-Relayers from OpenZeppelin will also not help without [further preparation](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/how-to-use-defender-relayer-provider-properly-to-pay-for-someone-elses-transaction/31786/2?u=oxuw4) of smart contracts which are required to support meta-transactions. So it's not usable for conventional, already existing smart contracts without these capabilities.

Do you guys follow the same approach like I did in my list above, or is there something that I don't have in my mind yet which would be a better approach?